# Why do I need to ensure that format in fprintf_s is not a user-defined string?

Tags: c, printf

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-s-fprintf-s-l-fwprintf-s-fwprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170

```
int fprintf_s(
   FILE *stream,
   const char *format [,
   argument_list ]
);
```

format
Format-control string.

```
fprintf_s (stdout, "%s", "Hello" );
```

> Important
> Ensure that format is not a user-defined string.

What does it mean? Do not do like that:

```
char user_defined_str [100] = "%s";
fprintf_s (stdout, user_defined_str, "Hello");
```

? If "yes" - why? What is the problem?

I tried to read and expected "yes", but don't understand why this should be avoided.

Comment: `char user_defined_str [100] = "%s";` Thats not a user defined string.

Comment: How would you check user pass compatible format?

Comment: There are better ways to do this in `c++` but you appear to be learning the `c`  ways. For starters a string in `c++` is `std::string`

Comment: Related - the [Mazda infotainment system crash](https://github.com/Hamled/mazda-format-string-bug) triggered by playing certain podcasts, due to user-defined format strings.  ([More info](https://www.reddit.com/r/gimlet/comments/bdxht4/hey_its_ben_from_the_reply_all_episode_140_i_have/))

Comment: In the same way, with database, see [exploit of mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @DrewDormann Wow, that's really sloppy

Comment: @Jarod42 There was a massive (and very public) hack of an ISP called TalkTalk over here via an SQL injection attack.  Took them ages to get their reputation back (so I got a really cheap deal ).

Comment: I believe this question is simply a misunderstanding of who "user" is, in the phrase "user-defined string".

Comment: The warning is about strings provided by the user of your program, e.g. by reading the format to use from stdin. This could result in `"%s%s%s%s%s"` being used as format...

Comment: @DrewDormann Right, even the C++ standard uses the term "user-defined" in a completely different meaning: _user-defined type, user-defined literal, user-defined conversion…_

Comment: @PaulSanders: It's annoyingly common for `%n` to trigger crashes. Just a couple years ago it was discovered that a wifi name `%p%s%s%s%s%n` would cause all nearby iPhones to bootloop. Worse, `%@` could be used for remote-code-execution.  https://therecord.media/that-iphone-wifi-crash-bug-is-far-worse-than-initially-thought

Comment: Don't use _s functions, and don't use the printf family functions in C++.

Comment: @DrewDormann, I always thought that "user-defined" is about a coder writing code. For example, if I write char format[] = "%s %s" - this is "user-defined". But in the MS tutorial above this means "user of program".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant term here is "format string attack".

Let's take your code and change it a bit

```
char user_defined_str [100];
fgets(user_defined_str, sizeof(user_defined_str), stdin);
fprintf_s (stdout, user_defined_str, "Hello");
```

Now suppose what happes if the user supplies the format string `%s %s`? There's no further argument passed to `fprintf_s`, but the function doesn't know this. So it will just attempt to print a string from where that pointer on the argument would be, but in this case it's going to be some garbage value.

This might be used to expose data from within the process, like cryptographic keys, that are not supposed to be exposed. But things are even worse than that. Suppose it's not `fprintf_s` that's getting a user defined format string, but `snprintf_s`. Then by supplying a sufficiently crafted format string it'd be possible to clobber parts of the process, thereby injecting code into it. Consider this is happening in a tool that's processing data coming in from the Internet: That's how security vulnerabilities happen.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why did you use "-1"?

Comment: `-1` because habit and muscle memory. There's unfortunately no consistency in the C standard library which functions do respect the terminating null and which don't. And because I can't keep that in my memory, and I don't want to consult the documentation each and every time, I just play it save.

Comment: very nice habit, thanks for information.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if your code was this:

```
void PrintUserName(const char* s)
{
    printf(s);
}
```

Seem innocuous, right?  Well, let's say on the form I filled out when I registered an account, I typed this as my user name that gets saved into some database or file:

`Haxor: %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x ... %s`

All of a sudden, that printf statement above is getting interpreted as:

```
printf("Haxor: %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x ... %s");
```

with no arguments to back up those %x %s format specifiers. It will likely show some random garbage off the stack. That might introduce undefined behavior. Perhaps even crash. Or it could even lead to me being able to see the passwords of other users...

A better implementation of the above:

```
void PrintUserName(const char* s)
{
    printf("%s", s);

}
```

Now the formatting characters introduced when I typed my name into your program are no longer interpreted.  They just get printed as-is.

Same holds for other variations of printf including sprintf, fprintf, etc...

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I cannot pick more than one answer :-(.